# Executable program will not run

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, executable

I was trying to run Monero-cli one my Ubuntu laptop and it wont let me run the executable file after the start.sh file. It said Permission denied on both the executable and start.sh and I could not find help for problem on google or askubuntu.com.

Log:

```
 czho@czho-Latitude-D630:/media/czho/ETC/monero-gui-v0.13.0.4$ sh 
./start-gui.sh
./start-gui.sh: 6: ./start-gui.sh: Bad substitution
./start-gui.sh: 7: ./start-gui.sh: ./monero-wallet-gui: Permission 
denied

czho@czho-Latitude-D630:/media/czho/ETC/monero-gui-v0.13.0.4$ 
./monero-wallet-gui
bash: ./monero-wallet-gui: Permission denied
```

Comment: ... given the `/media/czho/ETC/monero-gui-v0.13.0.4` path, I suspect the file is located on external media whose filesystem and/or mount options do not support execution

Comment: as steeldriver said if your miner is on a USB stick get it copied onto your ubuntu drive and execute it from there ...  if you then get execute errors you can fix using  `chmod +x filename1` as Klufy said ... this this make sense

Comment: That worked, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kulfy and @steeldriver said, move the program into main file system and run

```
chmod +x FILENAME
```

and as I said I did not come up with this, @kulfy and @steeldriver did.